i face query parameter error when api call use tmdp api
i have error on getMovieByGenre with on query parameter thaat error show No value passed for parameter 'with_genres' but i saw all code all is correct but didnt know how it give error in project and code is
gitCodeenter code here
the app is just when user click on genre the genre is generate and through that genre is the all movie related to that genre is show in home fragment
package com.example.movieapp.Retrofit

import com.example.movieapp.model.genere.GenreResponse
import com.example.movieapp.model.popularMovie.MovieResponse
import com.example.movieapp.utils.Constants.API_KEY
import retrofit2.Response
import retrofit2.http.GET
import retrofit2.http.Query

interface ApiInterface {

    @GET("movie/popular")
    suspend fun getPopularMovies(@Query("page") page: Int, @Query("api_key") api_key: String =API_KEY): Response<MovieResponse>

    @GET("genre/movie/list")
    suspend fun getGenres(@Query("api_key") api_key: String =API_KEY): Response<GenreResponse>

    @GET("discover/movie")
    suspend fun getMoviesByGenres(@Query("page") page: Int,@Query("api_key") api_key: String =API_KEY, @Query("with_genres") with_genres: String): Response<MovieResponse>


}

package com.example.movieapp.repository

import com.example.movieapp.Retrofit.ApiInterface
import javax.inject.Inject

class ApiRepository  @Inject  constructor( private val apiInterface:ApiInterface) {
    suspend fun getPopularMovies(page: Int) = apiInterface.getPopularMovies(page)
    suspend fun getGenres() = apiInterface.getGenres()
    suspend fun getMovieByGenre(page: Int,with_genres: String) =apiInterface.getMoviesByGenres(page,with_genres)
}

some code i delete so u can see  figure out error
package com.example.movieapp.viewmodel

import android.util.Log
import androidx.lifecycle.MutableLiveData
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModel
import androidx.lifecycle.viewModelScope
import com.example.movieapp.model.genere.GenreResponse
import com.example.movieapp.model.popularMovie.MovieResponse
import com.example.movieapp.repository.ApiRepository
import dagger.hilt.android.lifecycle.HiltViewModel
import kotlinx.coroutines.launch
import javax.inject.Inject

@HiltViewModel
class ApiViewModel @Inject constructor (private  val apiRepository: ApiRepository): ViewModel() {


    val genreList = MutableLiveData<GenreResponse>()
    val popularMovieList = MutableLiveData<MovieResponse>()
    val genreMoviesList = MutableLiveData<MovieResponse>()
    val emptyList = MutableLiveData<Boolean>()
    val loading = MutableLiveData<Boolean>()


    fun loadMoviesByGenre(with_genres :String) = viewModelScope.launch {
        loading.postValue(true)
        try {
            val response = apiRepository.getMovieByGenre(1, with_genres)
            if (response.isSuccessful) {
                genreMoviesList.postValue(response.body())
            } else {
                // Log error if response is not successful
                Log.e("ApiViewModel", "Error loading movies by genre: ${response.message()}")
            }
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            // Log exception if an error occurs during the API call
            Log.e("ApiViewModel", "Exception loading movies by genre: $e")
        } finally {
            loading.postValue(false)
        }
    }

}

package com.example.movieapp.ui.fragment

import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import androidx.fragment.app.viewModels
import androidx.lifecycle.Observer
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager
import com.example.movieapp.adapter.GenerMovieAdapter
import com.example.movieapp.adapter.PopularMovieAdapter
import com.example.movieapp.databinding.FragmentHomeBinding
import com.example.movieapp.repository.ApiRepository
import com.example.movieapp.ui.SpaceItemDecoration
import com.example.movieapp.viewmodel.ApiViewModel
import dagger.hilt.android.AndroidEntryPoint
import javax.inject.Inject

@AndroidEntryPoint
class HomeFragment : Fragment() {
    private lateinit var binding: FragmentHomeBinding
    private val viewModel: ApiViewModel by viewModels()
    @Inject
    lateinit var movieAdapter: PopularMovieAdapter
    @Inject
    lateinit var genreAdapter: GenerMovieAdapter

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
//        viewModel.loadUpcomingMoviesList()
        viewModel.loadGenreList()
        viewModel.loadPopularMoviesList()
    }

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        binding= FragmentHomeBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        return binding.root
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

        preparePopularMovies()
        viewModel.loadPopularMoviesList()
        observePopularMovies()

        prepareGenreRecyclerView()
        viewModel.loadGenreList()
        observeGenres()

        // Observe genre movies list
        observeGenreByMovies()



    }

    private fun observeGenreByMovies() {
//        // Observe genre item click event
//        genreAdapter.setOnItemClickListener { genre ->
//            // Load movies by the selected genre
//            viewModel.loadMoviesByGenre(genre.id.toString())
//        }
//
//        viewModel.genreMoviesList.observe(viewLifecycleOwner) { movies ->
//            movieAdapter.differ.submitList(movies.results)
//            binding.rvMovie.apply {
//                layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(requireContext())
//                adapter = movieAdapter
//            }
//        }
        binding.apply {
//            // Genre List
//            viewModel.genreList.observe(viewLifecycleOwner) {
//                genreAdapter.differ.submitList(it.genres)
//                genresRecycler.initRecycler(
//                    LinearLayoutManager(requireContext(), LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false), genreMoviesAdapter
//                )
//            }

            //Genres Movies List
            genreAdapter.setOnItemClickListener {
                viewModel.loadMoviesByGenre(it.id.toString())
                viewModel.genreMoviesList.observe(viewLifecycleOwner) {
                    movieAdapter.submitList(it.results)
                    binding.rvMovie.apply {
                        adapter = movieAdapter
                        layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(requireContext(), LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false)
                        addItemDecoration(SpaceItemDecoration(20)) // Add 20dp of spacing

                    }
                }
                tvPopular.text =it.name
            }
        }

    }

    private fun observePopularMovies() {
        viewModel.popularMovieList.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer { movies ->
            movieAdapter.differ.submitList(movies.results)
        })
    }

    private fun observeGenres() {
        viewModel.genreList.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer { genres ->
            genreAdapter.differ.submitList(genres.genres)
        })
    }


    private fun prepareGenreRecyclerView() {
        genreAdapter = GenerMovieAdapter()
        binding.rvGenre.apply {
            adapter = genreAdapter
            layoutManager =
                LinearLayoutManager(requireContext(), LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false)
            addItemDecoration(SpaceItemDecoration(20)) // Add 20dp of spacing

        }
    }

    private fun preparePopularMovies() {
        movieAdapter = PopularMovieAdapter()
        binding.rvMovie.apply {
            adapter = movieAdapter
            layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(requireContext(), LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false)
            addItemDecoration(SpaceItemDecoration(20)) // Add 20dp of spacing

        }
    }


}

the error ias just  with     suspend fun getMovieByGenre(page: Int,with_genres: String) =apiInterface.getMoviesByGenres(page,with_genres) this line   where bold character are show error No value passed for parameter 'with_genres' i  just want to know why error show when code is right

got the  answer   If your function have default value kept it as a last parameter as I see apikey you have passed as 2nd parameter keep its as 3rd and make with_geners as a 2nd parameter so after that the code is look like

@GET("discover/movie")
suspend fun getMoviesByGenres(@Query("page") page: Int,@Query("with_genres") with_genres: String,@Query("api_key") api_key: String =API_KEY): Response
